# Web Data fetch is not updating

Tags: excel, vba, web, fetch

I am beginner at VBA. I have done the below code by referring to lot of articles found online.

I am trying to fetch API data from a website. It is taking the first fetch and I need the data to be fetched every 5 mins. But it is not refreshing at all. What can I do? Can anyone have a look at the code and advise?

I am using the below code to get the JSON data and later I am extracting using a JSON parser.

```
Sub FetchOptionChain()
        
        Dim Json As Object
        Dim webURL, webURL2 As String, mainString, subString
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        Dim k As Integer
        Dim l As Integer
        Dim dtArr() As String
        Dim request, request2 As Object
        Dim HTML_Content As Object
        Dim requestString As String
        
        webURL2 = "https://www.nseindia.com/"
        webURL = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY"
        
        subString = "Resource not found"
        
        Set HTML_Content = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        
        'Get the WebPage Content to HTMLFile Object
        With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", webURL2, False
        .send
        
        End With

FetchAgain:
        
        With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", webURL, False

        
        'Found online that I have to add the below to remove the cached results. Adding this is hanging the excel and it never comes out of it. Excel is hanging here
        
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36"

        .send
        
        mainString = .ResponseText

        
        
        
If InStr(mainString, subString) <> 0 Then

' Data has not been fetched properly. Will wait two seconds and try again.

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))
GoTo FetchAgain
```

Comment: That shouldn't compile since there is a end with, a end if and a end sub missing. But apart from that, why are you fetching from different webpages in the different parts of the code?

Comment: When I add the three missing pieces mentioned above it seems to work fine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ9jb.png This is a debug.print of mainString

Comment: Oh, I missed to enter the End if and End Sub parts, the code is running actually the first time. But when I add the "RequestHeader" commands it hangs at .send command and excel never comes out of that state. I have to then force kill.  I am using Excel 2016. Not sure, what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Added end with, end if and end sub. And fixed indenting to make code easier to read.

```
Sub FetchOptionChain()
    
    Dim Json As Object
    Dim webURL, webURL2 As String, mainString, subString
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim l As Integer
    Dim dtArr() As String
    Dim request, request2 As Object
    Dim HTML_Content As Object
    Dim requestString As String
    
    webURL2 = "https://www.nseindia.com/"
    webURL = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY"
    
    subString = "Resource not found"
    
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '''  I don't understand this part though  '''
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Set HTML_Content = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    
    'Get the WebPage Content to HTMLFile Object
    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", webURL2, False
        .send
    End With
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ''''''''''''''''  To here  ''''''''''''''''''
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    
FetchAgain:
    
    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", webURL, False

        
        'Found online that I have to add the below to remove the cached results. Adding this is hanging the excel and it never comes out of it. Excel is hanging here
        
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36"

        .send
        
        mainString = .responseText
    End With
        
        
        
    If InStr(mainString, subString) <> 0 Then
    
        ' Data has not been fetched properly. Will wait two seconds and try again.
        
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
        GoTo FetchAgain
    End If
End Sub
```

But it runs and works as expected for me.

Comment: Hi, if I try to fetch the WebURL directly, it gives me "Resource not found" message. So I fetch the parent site using WebURL2 and then call the WebURL site and then the JSON data can be fetched. I think it has something to do with cookies may be. Not sure. My code is calling this function every 5 mins. But it keeps giving me the same data again and again, unless I restart the excel.

Comment: Every 5 mins minimum. Data changes in the site between 3 to 5 mins or so, not fixed. As of now, markets have closed, so that last update seen will be at 3.30PM (GMT + 5.30)

Comment: This data is also appearing in tabular format at https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain .https://ibb.co/64RZj9d . If there is a way to extract this table to excel, that also will help instead of the above code.